# Can't find which control is throwing error angular 2

Tags: angular

I have an angular2 project where I'm getting an error in the console log, which looks like it is referring to a form control. However, the error is so generic, I can't see how you would troubleshoot it.

The full error is this:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Loading chunk 20 failed.
Error: Loading chunk 20 failed.
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptComplete (bootstrap d4434bb2fbdb690e5b54:103)
    at HTMLScriptElement.W (polyfills.js:3)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.js:3)
    at p (polyfills.js:2)
    at HTMLScriptElement.v (polyfills.js:2)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptComplete (bootstrap d4434bb2fbdb690e5b54:103)
    at HTMLScriptElement.W (polyfills.js:3)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.js:3)
    at p (polyfills.js:2)
    at HTMLScriptElement.v (polyfills.js:2)
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.reject (polyfills.js:3)
    at Tab.NavControllerBase._fireError (nav-controller-base.js:322)
    at Tab.NavControllerBase._failed (nav-controller-base.js:310)
    at nav-controller-base.js:365
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:3890)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
```

Comment: Are you using @angular/cli? Are you running this in development mode? Normally there would be some source maps pointing to the original code, not the minified version.

Comment: Hi Tsvetan, I am using @angular/cli, but I don't see any source maps pointing to original code in this instance.